# Bitwise Operations in Java mainly AND

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Firstly, apologies if this question ends up being a duplicate.

I am trying to do some stuff with bits in Java. And I have a need to get awkward amounts of bits in a single variable. So I am still using a byte but want to only store like 7 bits or 4 bits.

So lets say I have a byte which is something like '1101 0110' and I want to get the '0110' at the end. I have seen someone do this: (byte)(b & 0x0F) where b is a byte.

So the way I understand what happens here is: b (1101 0110) is ANDed with 0x0F (0000 1111) then turned to int and casted back to byte.

```
1101 0110 & 
0000 1111 
---------
0010 0110 -> 0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0010 0110 -> 0010 0110
```

In this instance, I did not get the 4 bits, i got the whole byte and not what I started with either. Am I misunderstanding how the bitwise and works?
I am pretty sure that this works somehow, but I am at a loss how.
**Could someone explain this please?**

I would think that doing the following would yield a more reliable result:
(byte) ((b<<4)>>>4)
This way I can make sure that the first 4 bits are always 0.

Comment: `1101 0110 & 0000 1111 = 0010 0110` - this equation is wrong.

Comment: Yes, `1101 0110 & 0000 1111 = 0000 0110`.

Comment: Why? doesnt AND = 1 if both bits are the same? Or am i thinking of something else?

Comment: That's XOR, not AND.

Comment: @Atspulgs `&` results in 1 only if the **two** bits are 1, 0 in all other cases.

Comment: I see, I must have gotten confused about which is which somewhere along the way. Thanks you guys for the quick answers.
Had to think about this in terms of power after you pointed it out and it makes sense that only two 1's would make a 1 as both ends have to have power to have enough to get through.

XOR.... why didnt I make the connection there x.x

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect as well as provided example: AND is always reliable. The reason why it's used more often is that it's more flexible. This way you can replace with zeroes not only the highest bits, but any bits you want just supplying the appropriate mask. Also using shift you should pay additional attention to the sign bit which is unnecessary when you use AND.